# Compiling Simulink Model based on NI Veristand and error: The name cannot start or end with / character

Tags: matlab, simulink

When Compiling Simulink Model based on NI Veristand
, I get a Model error - Error: NI Veristand Error: Invaild character in ‘*model path*’, exiting code generation. The name cannot start or end with / character.Then I check the model in model of the path, but don’t find relative character.
Finally I need to do something to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name of simulink model hides part. And Compiling Simulink Model is correct after deleting hidden part.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This error may appear if some of the Simulink blocks are unnamed. Please make sure all blocks are named and try compiling again.